# Python Decorated Function Args

Tags: python-3.x, python-decorators, args

I am facing a weird issue where sometimes my decorated function is receiving arguments and sometime not.

The code is as such:

main.py

```
@Authenticator.authenticate_admin
def action_snapshot(username, token, payload):    
    .
    .
    .
```

authenticator.py

```
class Authenticator:

@staticmethod
def authenticate_admin(func):
    
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):

        print(f"ARGS: {args}")

        # ! Execute function
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
        
    return wrapper
```

So if i try to call the function in my main like that:

```
action_snapshot(username, token, payload)
```

the code works fine and i receive the args.

However if i call it like that:

```
action_snapshot(
    username=username, 
    token=token
    payload=payload
)
```

the args is empty.

Any idea why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're still receiving them, but because you're passing them as **keyword** arguments, they're in `kwargs` instead of `args`